# Programmatically register function as a test function in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to programmatically add or mark a function as a test-case in pytest, so instead of writing

```
def test_my_function():
    pass
```

I would like to do something like (pseudo-api, I know neither `pytest.add_test`  nor `pytest.testcase` exist by that identifier).

```
def a_function_specification():
    pass

pytest.add_test(a_function_specification)
```

or

I would like to do something like

```
@pytest.testcase
def a_function_specification():
    pass
```

Basically I would like to write some test-case-generating decorator that isn't exactly working like `pytest.mark`/parametrizing which is why I started to dig into the internals but I haven't found an obvious way how this can be done for python code.

The YAML example in the pytest docs seem to use pytest.Item but I have a hard time mapping this to something that would work within python and not as part of a non-Python-file test collection.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from [version 2.6](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id155), pytest support:

> nose-style `__test__` attribute on modules, classes and functions, including unittest-style Classes. If set to False, the test will not be collected.

So, you need to add this attribute.

One approach is:

```py
def not_a_test1():
    assert 1 + 2 == 3

not_a_test1.__test__ = True
```

Another is:

```py
def make_test(func):
    func.__test__ = True
    return func

@make_test
def not_a_test2():
    assert 1 + 2 == 3
```